# BLE Device Scan not working in Dialogfragment

Tags: android

Here I have a listview to show the list of scanned ble devices. This is working fine in ListActivity, but I want to do the same scan on DialogFragment on a button click. The working code which I have used in ListActivity is not working in DialogFragment. It is not even showing the Dialogfragment itself when I click on Button to trigger the dialog. so I have added a time with handler for 1500ms. then It shows only the Dialog title but not the list of scanned device. any idea to achieve list of scanned devices in Dialogfragment

```
public class DeviceScanDialogFragment extends DialogFragment 
{
private static final String TAG = "DeviceScan";
private LeDeviceListAdapter mLeDeviceListAdapter;
private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
private boolean mScanning;
private Handler mHandler;
private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1;
// Stops scanning after 10 seconds.
private static final long SCAN_PERIOD = 10000;

private BluetoothDevice selectedDevice;
private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());
private String calledFrom;

//persist the value about where to start the application
public static boolean isVerified = false, isPinChanged = false, isFingerPrintRegistered = false;
private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
private ListView listview;

public DeviceScanDialogFragment() {

}

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mHandler = new Handler();
    // Use this check to determine whether BLE is supported on the device.  Then you can
    // selectively disable BLE-related features.
    if (!getActivity().getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_BLUETOOTH_LE)) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), R.string.ble_not_supported, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        getActivity().finish();
    }

    // Initializes a Bluetooth adapter.  For API level 18 and above, get a reference to
    // BluetoothAdapter through BluetoothManager.
    final BluetoothManager bluetoothManager =
            (BluetoothManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
    mBluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();

    // Checks if Bluetooth is supported on the device.
    if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
        //   logger.info("Bluetooth adapter is null");
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), R.string.error_bluetooth_not_supported, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        getActivity().finish();
        return;
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_dialog_fragment, container);
    listview = (ListView) rootview.findViewById(R.id.list);
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Executed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    //   getDialog().getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getDialog().setTitle("Scan List Title");
    return rootview;
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    // Ensures Bluetooth is enabled on the device.  If Bluetooth is not currently enabled,
    // fire an intent to display a dialog asking the user to grant permission to enable it.
    if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
        //    logger.info("Enabling bluetooth");
        Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
    }

    listview.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Initializes list view adapter.
            mLeDeviceListAdapter = new LeDeviceListAdapter();
            listview.setAdapter(mLeDeviceListAdapter);
            scanLeDevice(true);
        }
    },1500);

}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // User chose not to enable Bluetooth.
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_ENABLE_BT && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
        getActivity().finish();
        return;
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    scanLeDevice(false);
    mLeDeviceListAdapter.clear();

    //   save(isVerified, isPinChanged, isFingerPrintRegistered);
}

private void scanLeDevice(final boolean enable) {
    if (enable) {
        // Stops scanning after a pre-defined scan period.
        mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mScanning = false;
                if (mBluetoothAdapter != null) {
                    mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
                    if (mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices().size() == 0)
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No Device Found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    if (getActivity() != null) {
                        if (isVisible())
                            dismiss();
                    }
                }
                //                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        }, SCAN_PERIOD);

        mScanning = true;
        //   logger.info("Scanning without UUIDs");
        mBluetoothAdapter.startLeScan(mLeScanCallback);

        /*UUID[] uuids = new UUID[1];
        Log.e(TAG, "Length of UUID[]= " + uuids.length);
        uuids[0] = UUID.fromString(SampleGattAttributes.JACKET_UUID);
        logger.info("Scanning with UUIDs");
        mBluetoothAdapter.startLeScan(uuids, mLeScanCallback);*/

    } else {
        mScanning = false;
        mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
    }
    //      invalidateOptionsMenu();
}

// Adapter for holding devices found through scanning.
private class LeDeviceListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> mLeDevices;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public LeDeviceListAdapter() {
        super();
        mLeDevices = new ArrayList<BluetoothDevice>();
        mInflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    }

    public void addDevice(BluetoothDevice device) {
        if (!mLeDevices.contains(device)) {
            mLeDevices.add(device);
        }
    }

    public BluetoothDevice getDevice(int position) {
        return mLeDevices.get(position);
    }

    public void clear() {
        mLeDevices.clear();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mLeDevices.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return mLeDevices.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        ViewHolder viewHolder;
        // General ListView optimization code.
        if (view == null) {
            view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem_device, null);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.deviceAddress = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.device_address);
            viewHolder.deviceName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.device_name);
            view.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }

        BluetoothDevice device = mLeDevices.get(position);
        final String deviceName = device.getName();
        Log.i(TAG, "name:" + deviceName + ", Address :" + device.getAddress());
        if (deviceName != null && deviceName.length() > 0) {
            viewHolder.deviceName.setText(deviceName);
            if (deviceName.contains("Test")) {
                selectedDevice = mLeDeviceListAdapter.getDevice(position);
                if (selectedDevice != null) {
                    Intent intent;
                    intent = new Intent(getActivity(), NavigationDrawerActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("address", selectedDevice.getAddress());

                    if (mScanning) {
                        mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
                        mScanning = false;
                    }
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        } else {
            viewHolder.deviceName.setText(R.string.unknown_device);
        }
        viewHolder.deviceAddress.setText(device.getAddress());

        return view;
    }
}

// Device scan callback.
private BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback mLeScanCallback =
        new BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback() {

            @Override
            public void onLeScan(final BluetoothDevice device, int rssi, byte[] scanRecord) {
                getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        mLeDeviceListAdapter.addDevice(device);
                        mLeDeviceListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                });
            }
        };

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView deviceName;
    TextView deviceAddress;
}
```

}

On Button click I am Calling this method to trigger the Dialogfragment

```
 public void showScanDialog() {
    FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    DeviceScanDialogFragment dialog = new DeviceScanDialogFragment();
    dialog.show(manager, "devicescan");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything is working fine when I turned off wifi, because BLE won't stable with wifi and Using BLE in Marshmallow Devices will won't show the Scanned devices which are nearby. so just I have added permissions for location access for Marshmallow supported Devices, Then it worked fine.